# Squarespace - HTML editor in page description?

Tags: squarespace

I'm a WordPress user but I need to do a website using Squarespace.

I'd like to know if there is any way to change the page description editor to a html editor?

I need to add few images and format some text there.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [code block](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206543167-Using-the-Code-Block) to the page. Then you can enter whatever `html` you like in that code block.